# Dotnet Publish to Same Folder

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, dotnet-publish

What is the expected behavior when different, **independent** .csproj projects are built/published to the same folder using `dotnet publish`?

Imagine that `Alpha.csproj` might require NuGet package `foo` at 1.0.0, and that project `Bravo.csproj` might require version 2.0.0 of the same NuGet dependency.  My concern is that two separate `dotnet publish` invocations on these distinct projects, pointed at the same target folder, will cause the `foo` dependency to be overwritten...thus breaking the deployment.

I know that NuGet often stores its binaries in subfolders, often distinguished by version numbers, but it is also common that it places the dependencies directly into the main publish-folder.  So, at face value there is room for unexpected conflicts.

So far the way I've solved this **anticipated** problem is to place both projects into the same solution, and then publish the solution. I figure that a single publish command is smart enough to resolve the differences (storing different dependency versions of `foo` into different subfolders). However, what if these projects are in different solutions?

I say "anticipated" problem because I've not actually spent time trying it.  I have tight deadlines and can't afford to deal with potentially obscure bugs emerging at runtime; I don't want to discover the answer to my question "the hard way."

Understanding this dynamic is particularly important for me, because I'm building .Net Core 3.1 plugins that I'd like to publish/deploy to an existing framework folder.  The application is designed to scan for new plugins and load them.

Comment: When the two projects are in the same solution, building will sort out the dependencies (and use the later version of the library). But with two projects in different solutions, I guess you'll be out of luck. Similarly if the dependency `foo` v1.0.0 and v2.0.0 have incompatible changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected behavior is that the last project published will overwrite existing files in the publish directory and thus can lead to dependency version conflicts.

[Single-file deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999) have a better chance of not creating a conflict when publishing to the same directory at the expense of a larger overall deployment size.

Comment: I'm stunned that, near as I can tell, no MS documentation explains this all-too-important behavior.  I'm annoyed that my main console-app "plugin platform" in my VS solution needs to have project-level dependencies on the plugins, just to ensure that there are no assembly conflicts.  I'd very much prefer that plugins can be independently published.  That said, perhaps I might achieve a solution if the plugins are published to subfolders rather than the main folder.  I'll look into that when I find time.